# Как написать текст на фото

Tags: java, android

Я пробовал через Draw2D, но там нельзя сохранить файл.
Если через Graphics2D, то Android Studio будет ругаться.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java awt не является частью Android SDK

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream); //Создаем Bitmap содержащий нужное фото
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ditmap); //Создаем Canvas на его основе
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);// Создаем кисть со сглаживанием
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)); //Ставим цвет
paint.setTextSize(20); //Ставим размер текста в пикселях
//делаем некоторые действия чтобы выяснить куда рисовать
Rect bounds = new Rect();//объект, в который положим размеры, которые займет наш текст
paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds); //вычисляем размеры текста, нарисованного этой кистью
int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2; //зная ширину и высоту текста, вычисляем координаты верхнего левого угла надписи в координатах вашего фото, поменяйте на то что вам нужно
int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2;
canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);//рисуем ваш текст в ваших координатах вашей кистью
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile); //создаем поток для записи в итоговый файл
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outputStream);//пишем в этот поток конвертированное в JPEG ил PNG изображение
fos.close();//закрываем поток
```

Мог что-нибудь забыть, скажем запись в файл точно надо в try/catch завернуть, но суть должны уловить